# Correcting exposure and white balance

Tags: image-processing

The scenario is as follows: I have an sRGB digital photograph of a painting and an 18% gray card. The card was in the same plane as the painting and the light perfectly uniform over the whole scene. The photograph was taken in auto mode, so the decisions about exposure and white balance were made by the camera and are somewhat off. I want to use the values I read for the gray card to correct the RGB channels of the image. I know that a perfectly exposed gray card should have sRGB=#7c7c7c which in linear space is approximately (0.202, 0.202, 0.202). I also know that the image was underexposed (the painting is quite light), but the darks were not clipped (the "blacks" read sRGB~#0a0a0a).

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Working on linear RGB, find the average pixel value for the gray card, let’s say `(a,b,c)`. Then multiply the red component of each pixel in the image by `0.202/a`, the green component by `0.202/b`, and th blue component by `0.202/c`.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Unfortunately, it results in values substantially greater than 1.0 for a large number of pixels.

Comment: @Eduardo: then use a value smaller than 0.202. I don’t know where you got that value, “perfectly exposed” is relative. Cameras have a limited range, you need to adjust exposure to keep the amount of light within that range. If you need to gray card to be exactly that value, you have to deal with overexposure in some other way. That said, if you are doing color analysis, and can keep your data as floating-point, there is no reason to stay within the [0,1] range.